# free sqlite tools

Tags: iphone, sqlite

looking for a free sqlite tool, any suggestions? I need a export, import functionality.

Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

I love SQLite manager: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817

Oddly enough, it's a firefox addon.

Comment: Luckily, it can be downloaded as XUL and then after unzipping be run as-if standalone with `firefox  -app SQLiteManager/application.ini`

Answer (score 2):

### MS Excel or Access can be used to browse SQLite data, too

I spent all day looking for a Windows tool to browse/explore contents of SQLite and tested many of the ones listed on http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools . Some I like and will explore further but many I find lacking for they either require install of other frameworks (.Net XXX), are too big, slow browse of big tables, weird interface, (mis)handling of BLOBs, lack of import/export facilities.

I have no issue using SQL from command line but in many occasions i find it useful to examine the data in file browser/spreadsheet fashion (as in MS Excel or Access).

Here is another alternative: if you have either Access or Excel installed on your machine, get ODBC driver and connect to the SQLite DB that way. While MS Office ain't free, for many people it is already installed on the PC.

**Important note when connecting from Access**: i was getting "*Reserved error -7778"* when trying to link the SQLite tables in, so i was assuming SQLite ODBC just won't work with MSAccess. Not so, i found after a bit of digging. All one has to do is **avoid using File Data Source** (File / Get External Data / Link tables... / ODBC - and then instead the "File DS" tab, go to the "Machine DS").

Answer (score 1):

SQLMaestro (http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/sqlite/datawizard/) has a good range of bulk import/export with what looks like over 20 formats (but since I don't need bulk import/export, I haven't tried this program). Oops ... look like i missed the "FREE" part

I'm using the **FREE** Firefox plugin SQLite Manager (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817) and it is really handy. It will handle a few import/export formats (CSV, SQL and XML)

SQLiteMan (http://www.sqliteman.com/) can import in half a dozen or so formats. Export doesn't seem obvious. Its **free** as well.

A few more **FREE** options (none of which I have tried include)

- SQLite Administrator(http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/)
- SQLiteStudio (http://sqlitestudio.one.pl/index.rvt)

Answer (score 1):

I've used http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/ when I need to quickly browse/edit an sqlite database. There's a very long list of other such tools at http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools

Answer (score 1):

Probably

[SQLiteMan](http://sqliteman.com/)

is about the best and most well known.

I personally like:

[SQLite Administrator](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/)

as it's very small and lightweight, but does have it's quirks.  However, there's a whole list of SQLite tools (both free, open source and commercial) here:

[Commercial and freeware Sqlite tools list](http://sb2.info/commercial-and-freeware-sqlite-tools-list-2/)

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Arca Database Browser with good results, available here:  http://xtras.tabuleiro.com/download/arca.htm.

Answer (score 0):

[SQLite Maestro](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/sqlite/maestro/) sounds like it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Now i use [Lita - SQLite Administration Tool](http://www.dehats.com/drupal/?q=node/58)

it's a free applications developed in Adobe Air.

the only thing that disturbs me is that it sorts the columns when you query.
Besides that it does what I want.