# iOS Data Storage - MAMP

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [free sqlite tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166703/free-sqlite-tools)

I am building an iPhone app which will store data in a database using sqllite. My question is, is it possible to test this on a local database, i.e. using MAMP server?

If so, could someone tell me how, or refer me to an article - I'm having a tough time figuring this one out...

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Is there a tool in xcode that allows me to look at the data in my xcdatamodel file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140478/is-there-a-tool-in-xcode-that-allows-me-to-look-at-the-data-in-my-xcdatamodel-fil), as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have successfully created an sqlite3 database on the iPhone, and assuming you are able to find it on your local hard drive (we're also assuming you are using the simulator) then you should be able to open that database with any tool that supports sqlite (personally I use a firefox plugin to do it, but any tool will work).

Answer (score 0):

I had used Mesa SQLite in one of my apps, I just found it good.  Check it out:
[MesaSQLite Homepage](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/26079/mesasqlite)